# File upload issue in Mongoose

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, mongoose-web-server

I am using Mongoose 6.18 version as an Embedded Web Server for my project. I have an issue when I try to upload a file to the server. I have a react application on the front end that uses axios api with formdata to send the file. ``

```
 await axios.post("http://" + window.location.host + "/upload", data, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        "Content-Length": ""
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.data.message);
      alert("File Upload successful"); 
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
      alert("File Upload not successful");
  });
```

On the server side I am using multipart handling as mentioned in this link. I use the function mg_file_upload_handler.
https://cesanta.com/blog/big-upload-example-mongoose-more-than-an-embedded-web-server-2/

By connection closes when the multipart chunks are in progress and every time only a part of file is uploaded. Can someone pls guide me in this.

Comment: what is the error

Answer (score 0):

Please use the latest version instead of an old 6.18, and use of the several upload methods, as described in the tutorial https://mongoose.ws/tutorials/file-uploads/